# Ember js download pdf nested under <li> which has an action

Tags: javascript, pdf, ember.js

How do I download the pdf file on click which has the following syntax

```
<a href =   "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" download >Click to download!</a>
```

And the pdf is associated with a model within the `<li>` item like this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li {{action action1}}>{{item}}
        <a href =   "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf" download >Click to download!</a>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>
```

Where as if I place the  tag outside the li it works fine and the pdf is downloaded. How do I make it work inside the `<li>` tag which has an action. 
Seems like the action is called first always!

[Demo](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zifeyihe/3/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Do you really want to perform an action on click, or just download the pdf?

Comment: I just want to download the pdf on click. But if I click on the list item, I want the alert to be displayed.

Comment: Ok, in this case i need need to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Try this:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zifeyihe/7/edit

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    action1: function(item){
      alert(item.color);
      window.document.location.href = item.link;
    }
  }
});
```

It just redirects to the PDF after alert was shown.

Comment: I would want the file to be downloaded on the same page and your fiddle is not working, pls check

Comment: I would not want to redirect, I am trying to download the pdf on the same page

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery